# Flex 1 child takes other siblings off the line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a display flex div with 2 child.

first one have a text with this css:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
flex: 1
```

this css when first child have a big text make second child take off the line and hide some of his content.

[image]

How can I set the width of the first child so that the second child does not go out of line and both widths are filled?

With this image you can see dom, css and the problem

[image]

Comment: well, you haven't actually used `flex`, your code says `display: block`

Answer (score 0):

For the second child `<div>`, set the width of it to `min-content` and disable any wrap

```css
width: min-content;
white-space: nowrap;
```